# Error using dbrda function for the vegan package in R

Tags: r, vegan

I am currently trying to run a dbRDA using the vegan package. 
I used three explanatory matrices to explain one response distance matrix:

`full.rda <- dbrda(bsim ~ genmat + envmat + spamat)`

The first one is a distance matrix while the last three are matrices (not data frames). I checked the dimnames attributes of each, no missing values either, overall everything seems ok...

> `dim(bsim)`
>
> [1] 380 380
>
> `dim(envmat)`
>
> [1] 380   6
>
> `dim(spamat)`
>
> [1] 380   3
>
> `dim(genmat)`
>
> [1] 380   2
>
> `all(attr(genmat, 'dimnames')[[1]] == attr(bsim, 'dimnames')[[1]])`
>
> [1] TRUE
>
> `all(attr(spamat, 'dimnames')[[1]] == attr(bsim, 'dimnames')[[1]])`
>
> [1] TRUE
>
> `all(attr(envmat, 'dimnames')[[1]] == attr(bsim, 'dimnames')[[1]])`
>
> [1] TRUE

but for some reason here the error message I get :

> `full.rda <- dbrda(bsim ~ genmat + envmat + spamat)`
>
> Error in dimnames(u) <- list(dnam[[1]], c(axnam, negnam)) : 
>     length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
>
> `traceback()`
>
> 3: ordConstrain(Y, X, Z)
>
> 2: ordConstrained(X, d$Y, d$Z, method = "dbrda")
>
> 1: dbrda(bsim ~ genmat + envmat + spamat)

I've seen people got this error when they were trying to do a corrplot and use a data frame instead of a matrix but that is not the issue here..

Is there anyone who might have suggestions or ideas to overcome this issue ?

I am using the version 3.5.1 of R and the version 2.5-2 of the vegan package.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you provide a reproducible example? What does `bsim` look like? Is that a symmetric square matrix of dissimilarities?

Comment: `bsim` is a distance matrix but the upper panel and the diagonal are left blank.

Comment: I tried to provide a reproductive example but the matrix is too big, I don't know what to do about it since when I used a certain smaller subset, I don't have an error message anymore. I thought the error might be related to the size of the dataset but with a different subset of the same size, the error message appeared again. I then thought there were some issues in one (or more) specific position(s) within this subset that leads to an error message. But if I split this subset in two, each sub-subset works well. I know it is confusing but I have no idea from what the error might come from...

Comment: I ran the exact same code but using a raw matrix instead of the distance matrix and it worked (I didn't really want to do that though). I still don't understand from what the error was coming from although at least I got the results of the analysis.

Comment: You wrote "bsim is a distance matrix but the upper panel and the diagonal are left blank." This will **not** be regarded as a distance (dissimilarity) matrix in **R**, but it is regarded as an ordinary rectangular data and will be used to calculate distances of your distances (which makes no sense). You *should* use **R** `"dist"` structures which you can make using function `as.dist()`. `vegan::dbrda()` will also recognize *symmetric* square matrices as dissimilarities, but your matrix was non-symmetric (lower triangle non-zero, upper triangle zero or NA).